# Storing String with name from file or text

Tags: java, string

[image]

In the image, Its not "store a string",Its "make a string".

My question is , I want to make a string with name and text according to what value we give(much more understood by the image).

Hope you understand the ques.

I have given no code as i don't no how to procced.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any design so far? Thing is, giving you a solution to that is not that hard, but then what? Do you think if you have that answer, you know enough to proceed with more sophisticated elements of your programming language, like for example ifs? In short: are you sure that you don't want to start with the basic tutorials first? Or at least read into how programming languages are build, tokens and parsing and grammar etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use as like this thinking more OOP

```
 class CMD{
        private String VarName;
        private String Value;
        public String getType() {
            return Type;
        }
        public void setVarName(String varName) {
            VarName= varName;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return Value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            Value = value;
        }

    }
```

and the main code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //cmd mystring = "this is string"
        String cmd="MyString=\"this is string\"";
        String[] str=cmd.split("=");
        Vector<CMD> myCMD=new Vector<CMD>();
        CMD c = null;
        c.setVarName(str[0]);
        c.setValue(str[1]);
        myCMD.add(c);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a way to start is to use jtextfield and addActionListener()

```
String CMDline=null; 
Action action = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        CMDline=textField.getText();
        doSomething(CMDline);
        textField.setText(">");
    } };

JTextField textField = new JTextField(10); 
textField.addActionListener( action );
textField.setText(">");
```

doSomething() where you need to split the String and get the name, type of variable & value.

Comment: I have simpified the ques to what i just want to know.

Comment: I thought the part about making a programming language would confuse others

Comment: @Aziuth,I feel you are right.But still I would like to get the answer

Comment: you shoud give example of what you want to clear things ,like so if i put in  JtextField mystering ="this is my string"; should output String mystering ="this is my string";

Comment: @Azuith,Yes I have done some design(and a lot),link(net beans project):

Comment: you got it . i want to do the same @dodomoh

Comment: example:  In the JTextArea we input" MyString = "this is my string" ";Now I want to create a new new java String named MyString having the value "this is my string".Hope that is what you are working on.

Comment: @Yash since it is just emulating a real Terminal you can Store these values in Vector() and the use them as you need

Comment: can you give an example @sdx11